# Unity2D: Sprite.Create doesn't work with what I need it to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been having problems with the Sprite.Create function lately. I'm using C# to program a box with a border that can stretch and change size, but I didn't want the white border to stretch. I tried to create my own texture, and when I printed out the values of some pixels, it seemed like that worked fine. But when I used the texture for Sprite.Create, it didn't work and just showed a gray square. Here is the code:

```
`void updateSprite(){
    transform.localScale = new Vector3 (scale.x, scale.y, 0);
    SpriteRenderer rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D ((int)(100*scale.x), (int)(100*scale.y));
    for (int y = 0; y < tex.height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < tex.width; x++){
            if(y < 2 || x < 2 || y >= tex.height-2 || x >= tex.width-2){
                tex.SetPixel(x, y, Color.white);
            }else{
                tex.SetPixel(x, y, Color.black);
            }
        }
    }
    print (tex.GetPixel (0, 0) + "," + tex.GetPixel(3, 3) + "," + tex.GetPixel(tex.width-1, tex.height-1));
    Sprite spr = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    rend.sprite = spr;
}`
```

The scale variable is a Vector2 that I can change before drawing the sprite so it doesn't stretch.
Thanks for your help. I'm using Unity 5, if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: What values are you using for `scale.x` and `scale.y`?

Comment: For both I am using 12 and 2. It always over 0 if that's what you're getting at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was actually really simple. First I had to add a "dummy" texture to the SpriteRenderer in the editor. I also had to add tex.Apply() to apply the changes.